# Difference between port mapping of Docker Service and Docker run

Tags: docker

Usually when we create docker container ( For example nginx ) and expose it to outside we use port mapping.

```
docker run -p 8091:80 --name container1 --net my-overlay-a nginx
docker run -p 8092:80 --name container1 --net my-overlay-a nginx ( if in this line if I specified 8091:80 then it create problem as on host machine 8091 already used to map 80 port of container1).
```

Now instead of docker run if I use docker service ( I did docker swarm init before that).

```
docker service create --name redis --replicas=2 --publish 8080:80 nginx
```

This will also create two containers but both are accessed by same port 8080.

How this is possible  ?

Comment: check the accepted answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407531/docker-swarm-scaling-behaviour-on-port-mapping?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker swarm use route mesh technology, ingress network. when you define port while creating service, service will expose same port in each node, even though created multiple containers.   and the swarm has inbuilt load balancer it will route traffic across all containers

Comment: Though This answer does not provide complete detail but it provide detail where to check for information. Actually your answer and suggestion by @AnouarZ help me to search for specific topic. Later I understand my self.